# How to import Metaio scenario into Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, metaio

I need to import a Metaio scenario into Android Studio in order to develop an application with it.

I have created an scenario using [this tutorial](https://dev.metaio.com/creator/tutorials/create-your-first-ar-scenario/index.html) and saved it into the a folder (named ARtest), [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eIuGF.png) are the files and folders that were generated by Metaio.

After that, I have started [this](https://dev.metaio.com/sdk/getting-started/android/running-the-tutorials-app/index.html) tutorial in order to import the porject to Android Studio.

At the first step it says to locate de **build.gradle** in **metaioSDK**\ **_Android**. I don't have any _Android folder, as it can be seen [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PHln.png), so I use the **build.gradle** file from there.

So, I start Android Studio, I select "Open Project" and select ARtest folder. It doesn't require any other operation like it says it the tutorial but the project after being imported looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPPIo.png) with red dots on the Java Classes and it cannot be run.

What did I do wrong and how to make it work?

Thanks.